# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a measurable set and $f: A \to \Bbb R$. Show that $m(\{x \in A \mid |f(x)| >c \}) \le \frac1c \int_A |f|$ for all $c>0.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a measurable set and $f: A \to \Bbb R$ an integrable function. Show that $$m(\{x \in A \mid |f(x)| >c \}) \le \frac1c \int_A |f|$$ for all $c>0.$

Since $|f|$ is non-negative I have that $\int_A |f| = \int_a f \cdot \chi_A$, but I don't really know other properties of the integral. Also I have that $$m(\{x \in A \mid |f(x)| >c \}) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k)$$ for covers $\{I_k\}_k$ of $\{x \in A \mid |f(x)| >c \}$.

I assume I somehow have to relate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k)$ and the integral $\int_a f \cdot \chi_A$ but I don't yet know how.

Looking at wikipedia it also seems that since $|f|$ is non-negative I can represent $\int_A |f|  = \sup\{\int_A s \mid 0<s<f\}$, where $s$ is a simple function e.g $s=\sum_{k=1} a_k 1_{A_k}$, where I assume the union of $A_k$'s are disjoint representation of $A$?

The integral $\int_A s$ can also be apparently expressed as $$\int_A s=\int_A \left(\sum_{k}a_k 1_{A_k}\right) = \sum_{k}a_k \int_A 1_{A_k}= \sum_{k}a_k \cdot m(A_k)$$ but no help from this. Any hints what to do here?

Comment: This is Chebychev or Markov inequality. For start, integrate $|f|$ on the set $|f(x)|>c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the monotonicity of Lebesgue integral. Since $|f|$ is non-negative, we have:

$\int\limits_A|f|\geq\int\limits_{A\cap \{|f|>c\}}|f|\geq\int\limits_{A\cap \{|f|>c\}}c=c\cdot m(A\cap\{|f|>c\})$

In the second inequality I used the fact that $|f(x)|\geq c$ for all $x\in A\cap\{|f|>c\}$. The last equality is true because the integral of the constant function $1$ is just the measure of the set.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\int_A |f|d\mu \geq \int_{\{x\in A:|f(x)|\geq c\}} |f|d\mu \geq \int_{\{x\in A:|f(x)|\geq c\}} cd\mu =c\mu (\{x\in A:|f(x)|\geq c\} )$$